# Resolution of equation such that $f(...f(x)...)=x$

Tags: functional-equations

I am wondering if it exits a way to find "easely" the solutions of an equation about a function $f$ such that $$f^{(n)}(x)=x$$

where $f^{(n)}$ is the n-th composition of $f$ itself.

Obviously the identity is a trivial solution, I'm asking for all solution depending on $n$.

---

For example I know that for $n=4$, if $$f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$ then $f^{(4)}(x)=x$

---

Any hints would be helpfull, thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not think that an "easy" solution exists for that.

Comment: Well, for composite $n$ you can construct factor solutions. Maybe if those are all the solutions for $n$ you can restate the problem as finding solutions for $f^{(p)}(x)=x$, $p$ prime.

Comment: Sorry, I actually think partition numbers come into play.

Comment: I dislike partition numbers. So it looks to be more difficult than I thought. Maybe instead of find them it exists a way to know a upper bond of how much solutions there are for any n ?

Comment: What are the domain and range of $f$? ((For any given $n > 1$, there are infinitely many functions $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ such that $f^n(x) = x$ for all $x$).

Comment: The solutions are infinite. For example, for $n=4$ you can use $f(x)=\frac{(k^2+1)/2+x}{k-x}$ for an arbitrary $k$. A similar parametric functon can be find easily other small $n$. For example, for $n=5$ I got $$f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(3 b^2+4
   b+\sqrt{5}
   (b+1)^2+3\right)+x}{b-x}$$ for arbitrary $b$.

Comment: Hum interesting and if n=100! ? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general answer that might help you.

Suppose we have a rational function
$$\rho(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
and we define the "coefficient matrix" of $\rho$ to be
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
then the coefficient matrix of $\rho \circ \rho$ or $\rho^2$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix} ^2$$
This theorem is rather trivial, and I will leave the proof to you.

If you know about [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), then you should know that
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{pmatrix} ^n=\begin{pmatrix} \cos n\theta & -\sin n\theta \\ \sin n\theta & \cos n\theta \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
Meaning that if we let 
$$\theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$
Then we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{pmatrix} ^n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
And so, since
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
is the coefficient matrix of the identity function $x$, if we take $\rho$ to be the rational function defined by the coefficient matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
Then
$$\rho^n(x)=x$$
and so $\rho$ can produce a solution to any functional equation in the form you asked about (though I'm sure it cannot be the only solution to any of them).

Does this help?